# (flutter) firebase auth apple signin firebase_auth/unknown] An unknown error has occurred

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, authentication

I can't find the wrong part in the apple signin settings and code, but an unknown error occurs.

this is the sign-in code.

```
Future<UserCredential> signInWithApple() async {
    final appleCredential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
      scopes: [
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
      ],
    );

    final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
      idToken: appleCredential.identityToken,
      accessToken: appleCredential.authorizationCode,
    );

    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential); <- error part
  }
```

Firebase Auth Console

[image: firebase auth console]

Apple Developer Pages

[image: Apple Developer Page]

[image: Apple Developer Page]

XCode Screenshot

[image: XCode]

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself!

First, I found something more.

If I run with

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
```

then

```
core/duplicate-app] A Firebase App named "[DEFAULT]" already exists
```

error occurs.

and with below code,

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
name: 'Project name', options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
then the app runs. but still can't login anonymously or apple login
```

I found a clue in [ Default ] right above and solved the problem.

That is.. Files not visible in VSCode but Xcode had it.

There are multiple googleservice-info.plist files... I don't know when they have put in there.. I'm so sorry

After deleting those files and adding a new googleservice-info.plist,

I was able to build and sign in the app without errors.

Thank you all.